# HDD 2.5" mobile rack without chipset, just direct connection to SATA

Tags: hard-disk

I am looking for the specified device. The use case is simple - I have an SSD-drive with linux and I use it both at home and at work. I'd prefer this to taking a notebook for different reasons, like low performace of mobile solutions, weight and so on.

The problem is that all mobile racks I saw have chips which are completely useless. I had a couple of them and both had lower performance then when the drive is connected directly.

So at the moment I connect the drive with a pair of SATA/SATA power cables, passed through the front panel of chasises.

But I'd like to make it more, let's say, fundamental.

What I am looking for is a rack without any logic, just direct connection to these two cables, no drivers, no anything. Sounds simple but I desperate to find it.

P.S. I live in Russia, so shipping to this country is required.

Answer (score 1):

[This seems to meet your needs, found on newegg.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817998228&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Accessories%20-%20Hard%20Drive-_-N82E16817998228&gclid=CNO866CNns8CFZSGfgod6zwE9Q&gclsrc=aw.ds)

If you look at the picture, it looks like it takes 1 power connection and 2 sata cables. Its from newegg, so I'm assuming they ship to russia, but if they don't I found about 2 dozen sellers of this product on google. I hope this fits the bill, let me know if I need to change my google searches to find something else.

Comment: At the first look it seems like what I need. Cannot guarantee that the connection is direct, though.  However, I didn't find an option for shipping to Russia or newegg. Also, I didn't mention this in the question, but I'd prefer the rack without doors. I mean I'd like to insert SSD into into like cartridge is inserted into old-school video consoles like NES. Maybe something like http://www.synchrotech.com/products-storage/sedna-sata-6gbps-internal-2.5-inch-ssd-hdd-sshd-dock-for-floppy-bays.html but again, I am not sure how it works internally.

Comment: Internally, they are all going to be pretty much the same. A mounted Sata port that allows easy and consistent sliding of the drive. In your case, the cheaper the better. Something with no additional features added on will likely not have any pcb's attached and will just be the direct connection you are looking for.